# Discord Ruby bot does not respond to user joining

Tags: ruby, discord, bots

I am creating a simple bot that interacts with a custom database. When a user joins the server in discord, the bot has to take his ID and compare it with the ID in the database. I decided to start small, just greet the user.
After writing some simple code, the bot starts up without any problems, but when a user joins the server, the bot simply doesn't respond. I tried other commands like: channel_create, the bot responds to them

P.S. In addition to this function, there are other commands in the bot code. Ruby v2.5.2

```
require 'pg'
require 'discordrb'
require 'dotenv/load'

bot = Discordrb::Commands::CommandBot.new(token: 'TOKEN',
                                          client_id: 'client_id',
                                          prefix: '!')

bot.member_join do
  bot.send_message(channel_id, 'Hi!')
end

bot.run
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the discord gem before but the docs say that you need to call `bot.run` in the code to tell the bot to run. It looks like you don't have that line in your code example.

https://github.com/shardlab/discordrb#usage

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to add this in the attached piece of code, but the original ```bot.run``` contains.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the bot to respond to 'Ping!' however I wasn't able to get the 'member_join' event to trigger.

Here is my code:

```
require 'discordrb'


bot = Discordrb::Bot.new token: 'mytoken'

puts "This bot's invite URL is #{bot.invite_url}."
puts 'Click on it to invite it to your server.'

bot.member_join do |event|
  puts 'this never seems to run' 
  event.send_message('Hi!')
end

bot.message(content: 'Ping!') do |event|
  puts 'this runs fine'
  event.respond 'Pong!'
end

bot.run
```

My advice is to open an issue with the Gem here: https://github.com/shardlab/discordrb/issues